# Login to delphi program from .net program

Tags: .net, delphi, authentication

I made a .net program that capture's and verifies finger prints to authenticate employee's.

One program we use is written in Delphi. so I'm looking for a way to authenticate the user using .net and then open the Delphi program and pass in this users credentials.

The best would be if I could fill in the log in screen even the Delphi program is open. but if that's not possible at least I need to open the program and pass in the credentials.

Comment: To paraphrase:  You have a .Net program that you want to have pass some string credentials to a Delphi program that may be running. If it's not running, you want the .Net program to also start the Delphi program? Is that correct?  Also, how secure does the passing of the credentials have to be?  Can the credentials be in an .ini file that the Delphi program would immediately delete, or must it be more secure?

Comment: Yes you got it right... I don't care much about security...

Comment: How does the Delphi program *expect* to have credentials given to it? If you don't have the power to change the Delphi program, then you need to know how it expects to be operated. Without that, you can't know what the .Net program will need to do.

Comment: I do have the power to edit the Delphi program. Currently it works with a small login form and the user types in his username and password. Now I made a .net app that looks up the user-name and password by using the employees finger tip...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send a windows message - see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645204/how-do-i-send-receive-windows-messages-between-vb6-and-c).

You could add a COM object to your Delphi app and call that from your .NET app (a more modern solution).

Comment: can you give me more details (or a link) on the 2'nd option please? It looks much better...

Comment: Do you have any Delphi Knowledge in the company?  Essentially you add an automation object to your delphi app which allows other application to communicate with it.  Start Here. http://www.gekko-software.nl/Delphi/

Comment: No I'm actually the .net guy... But I'll give it over for them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A better option I guess, since you can edit both programs, is to create a .NET Library that makes the biometric authentication and invoke it from the Delphi program. How? Check the JEDI project, in the Jcl (it's free) you can find how to instantiate a .NET VM, load a library and call a method (must be marked as COMVisible).

Check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048540/hosting-clr-in-delphi-with-without-jcl-example)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, here are your requirements. The items with an asterisk are the ones you need to have answered:

1. (*) How can a .Net program check if the Delphi program is running?
2. (*)  How can a .Net program start a Delphi program and wait until it is running?
3. .Net file creates an .ini file in an agreed upon folder.
4. (*) How can a .Net file send a simple "there are some credentials ready for pickup"-message to a Delphi application.
5. Delphi program reads the ini file.

No, this isn't a complete answer. So, downvoters, leave me alone! :-)  Not sure why I felt the need to paraphrase.

Comment: Amazing that someone felt the need to vote me down, in spite of my acknowledging that this wasn't an answer.  IMO, at least you should have had the courtesy of telling me WHY you felt the need to do that instead of hiding behind anonymity. My clarifying a question that is vague seems like a valid posting.